# Defino el index y sigue diciendo Notice: Undefined index: id_mater

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo esta pagina donde se muestran los archivos de una tabla que se encuentra en mysql.
En esta pagina vos seleccionas la carrera y despues deberia mostrarte el contenido/ los archivos.

> Se que Notice: Undefined index ocurre cuando en un array intentas
> acceder a un índice alfanumérico que no existe.

Pero el problema es que lo estoy definiendo y tiene un número pero sigue diciendo lo mismo.

funciones.php:

```
function verMaterialAlumnoPorID ()
{
    $id_mater = $_GET['id_mater'];
    $link = conectar();
    $sql = "SELECT mat.nombre, md.id_det, md.material, md.tipo, mat.id_mater, mat.id_curso 
    FROM materiales AS mat 
    INNER JOIN matedet AS md 
    ON mat.id_mater = md.id_mater 
    WHERE mat.id_mater = '". $id_mater ."'";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
    $curso = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)
    or die (mysqli_error($link));
    return $curso;

}
```

codigo donde se envian los datos:

```
   <?php  
   require 'funciones/cursada.php';
$cursadas = verCursadaAlumnoPorID();
$materiales = verMaterialAlumnoPorID($id_mater);
$id_mater = (isset($_SESSION['id_mater']) ? $_SESSION['id_mater'] : "Sin id_mater asignada");
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    
    <body>
      <h4>Material de la cursada:</h4>
        <?= $materiales['nombre'] ?>
        <?= $materiales['material'] ?>
        <?= $materiales['tipo'] ?>
    </body>
```

Error:

> Notice: Undefined index: id_mater in C:\xampp\htdocs...\cursada.php
> on line 128

La linea 128 es `$id_mater = $_GET['id_mater'];`

También probe con `$_POST` pero sigue con el mismo problema

Answer (score 0):

Para poder obtener el $_POST dentro de la función, primero debes pasarselo de algún modo.
Lo ideal es que lo obtengas en una variable fuera de la función.
De este modo, podrás usar esa variable en tu función o en cualquier otra que crees para el uso de esa variable.

**Puede ser `$_GET` o `$_POST`, es tu preferencia, pero debes pasarlo de algún modo a la funcion.**

```
$idmater = $_POST['id_mater'];
function verMaterialAlumnoPorID ($id_mater)
{
.......
}
```

Comment: Gracias, pero ahi probe de este metodo y sigue diciendo lo mismo pero esto se sumo: `Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function verMaterialAlumnoPorID(), 0 passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\....\contenidoCarreraAlumno.php on line 8 and exactly 1 expected in C:\xampp\htdocs\......\funciones\cursada.php:127 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\....\contenidoCarreraAlumno.php(8): verMaterialAlumnoPorID() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\.....\funciones\cursada.php on line 127`

Comment: No le agregaste el parámetro en donde llamas la funcion... `...Too few arguments to function verMaterialAlumnoPorID(), 0 passed...`

Comment: Perdon, no entiendo. Algo asi? `$materiales = verMaterialAlumnoPorID($id_mater);` Lo intente de este metodo pero sigue igual.

Comment: Si pero, tienes que pasarle `id_mater` que no se de donde se lo estás enviando.

Comment: Se envian en donde dice _codigo donde se envian los datos:_ Pero igual sigue diciendo `Notice: Undefined index` . Si es eso, no se como se pasan o envian a donde se deben enviar.

Comment: Ok ok, veo tu edicion, ahora, pon la carga de $id_mater, antes de la llamada de la funcion, por que tienes que cargarla antes de ejecutar la funcion.